# Specify dates on x-axis plot from pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, matplotlib, plot

I have this dataframe:

```
df.payout.head()
```

[image]

I am trying to plot stacked bar chart from pandas dataframe.

I want full date to be shown on X-axis label, though I only get only months if I use `grouped.index.month` or days for `grouped.index.days`:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df.payout = pd.to_datetime(df.payout)

grouped = df.groupby(pd.Grouper(key='payout', freq='M')).sum()
grouped.plot(x=grouped.index.month, kind='bar', stacked=True)

plt.show()
```

How do I get `payout` values in YYYY-MM-DD format on X-axis?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the desired date format on the index:

```
grouped.plot(x=grouped.index.strftime('%Y-%m-%d'), kind='bar', stacked=True)
```

Comment: thanks that worked. I'll choose your answer. offtopic: why I was downvoted?

Comment: Consider accepting it as an answer. I am not sure why you were down-voted, but If I had to guess, you didn't provide any sample data, just a screenshot which is not really helpful. Also, your question is about formatting date, the context of the stacked bar chart is redundant and may act as a diversion from the real problem.